# Declare UInt8Array variable in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, fs

How to declare function parameter of type UInt8Array in TypeScript?

```
import * as fs from "fs";
fs.readFile(fileName, (err: string, data: UInt8Array) => {
                if (err) {
                    return console.error(err);
                }
                console.log("file text: " + data.toString());
            });
```

I'm having an error:

> error TS2304: Cannot find name 'UInt8Array'

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your error message indicates a typo, i.e.

```
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'UInt8Array'
```

complains about `UInt8Array`. But the name you're looking for is probably [Uint8Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array), with a lowercase `i`.

Answer (score 1):

The following instantiations work in TypeScript 1.6 (the latest stable version at the time of writing):

```
let t01 = new Uint8Array([1, 2, 3, 4]);
let t02 = new Int8Array([1, 2, 3, 4]);  
let t03 = new Uint8Array([1, 2, 3, 4]);
let t04 = new Uint8ClampedArray([1, 2, 3, 4]);
let t05 = new Int16Array([1, 2, 3, 4]);
let t06 = new Uint16Array([1, 2, 3, 4]);
let t07 = new Int32Array([1, 2, 3, 4]);
let t08 = new Uint32Array([1, 2, 3, 4]);
let t09 = new Float32Array([1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5]);
let t10 = new Float64Array([1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5]);

let arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(16);
```

[Declare TypedArray with ArrayLike?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33332231/declare-typedarray-with-arraylike/33349781)

Comment: I don't understand this answer. I have Typescript 2.2.2 and I'm seeing the same issue as the OP. I am no closer to a solution after reading this answer.